# HighCharts draw a line in current month and year

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I already know how to draw a vertical line in the chart but it's a static value and I want to be dynamic. So what I want is to get the Index of the current month and year is there a function?.

Example:
Imagine that the current date is now = '27-03-2021'

> I need a function that retrieves the current month and year

Note: `this.value`, `this.category`, `this.point` always show **`undefined`** why can't I use it in the potLines area?

```
xAxis: {
  categories: ['01-08-2018', '01-10-2019', '31-02-2020', '27-03-2021', '01-01-1900'],

  plotLines: [{
    color: '#FF0000',
    width: 1,
    value: index = (function() {

      var value;

      if (this.category == '03-2021') { //Compare only the month and year
        value = //I want the Index of this position date 
      } else {
        value = //the length of the list

      }

      return value;
    })()
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dynamic way to set the plotLine

```js
let data = () => {
    let data = []
    let start = 1609455600000
    for(let i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    data.push([start + i * 2592000000, Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(30))]) 
  }
  return data
}


Highcharts.chart('container', {

        xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        plotLines: [{ 
                color: '#FF0000',
          width: 2,
            value: Date.now()
        }]
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: data(),
    }],

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <div id="container"></div>
```

I believe as per the API documentation that value only takes a value not a function. If you wish to use a function to you can do so in chart.events.load for example. Then you could try to get the `value`, `category`, `point` from the chart object using `this` keyword.